Elam and Assur, sons of Shem, were born before/during the Flood?
My question is based especially on the way the account of Shem's descendants in Genesis 10 is arranged:

Genesis 10:22 (KJV)
The children of Shem; Elam, and Asshur, and Arphaxad, and Lud, and Aram.

Note that Elam and Assur are listed before Arphaxad, where, normally, the bible usually lists someone's descendants in order of birth (that is, from oldest to youngest). However, Arphaxad was born two years after the flood:

Genesis 11:10 (KJV)
These are the generations of Shem: Shem was an hundred years old, and begat Arphaxad two years after the flood.

This clearly creates a chronological problem with the two accounts, as it seems unlikely to me that two children would be born to Shem in such a short period of time, especially after such an drastic event.
The alternative possibility, then, would be that the birth order in Genesis 10:22 is not chronological, but of importance to the narrative. Something similar occurs for Abraham and Shem himself, who are always listed ahead of their brothers, although Shem is probably the middle child (Since Ham must be the youngest according to Gen 9:24, and Japheth the oldest accordinh Gen 10:21), and Abraham the youngest (According to Acts 7:4, which places Abraham's birth at 130 Terah, meaning that children born after Terah's 70th birthday in Gen 11:26 be either Nahor or Haran).
But, in both cases above, the displacement of the patriarchs is understandable, as their importance and relevance compared to their brothers, in the context that Genesis brings (which is to trace the origin of the hebrew people) is clear. But why would Elam and Assur have greater importance compared to Arphaxad, who is the direct ancestor of the Hebrews?
So the problem remains, since we don't have enough time for them to be born before Arphaxad, nor plausible justification for moving them ahead of this one in the Table of Nations. Only the third option remains, could they have been born before or even during the Flood?

Giving the date of the third son does not necessarily mean something for the first and second sons. Born 2-years after the flood only dates his birth. Two years between the flood and the birth of Arphaxad is enough time for Elam and Asshur to be born, especially if Elam was conceived on the ark. Also Elam and Asshur could be twins. Attention is given to the birth of Arphaxad (not the other two) because he will be in the genealogy of Jesus (Luke 3:36).

Hmm, the possibility of them being twins is really interesting and I hadn't thought of it. I can now see them being born in the one year window between the flood and Arphaxad, good answer

This "problem" of genealogical priority in the descendants of Shem as recorded in Gen 10 is less of a problem that it appears.  In solving this, we need to recall several facts:

Only eight people entered the ark, 1 Peter 3:20
we do not know the order of Shem's children - there is not enough information as the OP correctly points out
the order listed in the genealogies is NOT necessarily the birth order as the OP has correctly observed.  Indeed, in Gen 10:1, the order listed is "Shem, Ham and Japheth", but we also know that Japheth was the older brother of Shem as per V21.
all we know about chronology is that Arphaxad was born 2 years after the flood.

In view of these facts, I offer the following "solutions" to the OP's question.  We could have either:

the birth order is not that listed in Gen 10:22 - quite possible given the above counter examples.
The fact that Arphaxad was born 2 years after the flood, does not prevent one older brother being born during the flood and another brother being born one year after the flood.

Both of these are possible but the first appears more likely.

That's a good answer, and I would also personally prefer the first explanation if something else supported it. I mean, I know the genealogies aren't in order, as I've pointed out before, but they still follow some kind of priority scheme apparently. If here it is not of natality, or of narrative importance, then what is it? Why does the author put them first?

@L.Rodrigues - they are placed in the order that the appear because they are more important to the story as distinct from chronology.

Possibility 3 - Assur and Elam are twins (or Assur and Arphaxad, or they could even be triplets), which gives plenty of time for them to all be born after the Flood. Though I'd tend to agree that option 1 is the most likely. (also random thought - it wouldn't be surprising if all three sons' wives came off the ark pregnant, I guess they didn't have much else to do while shut in...)

@user111403 I considered the possibility of them leaving the ark pregnant and giving birth immediately afterwards, but I think that would still leave a very short window of only 2 months between each pregnancy. But if they are twins that window it's a year, so I think at the moment that is my favorite theory

@L.Rodrigues do bear in mind that there's rounding going on. How exactly the author counts we can't be certain, but it's quite possible that Arphaxad was born two years and six or eight months after the Flood, which is enough to make the window a lot more plausible.

Genealogies, particularly in the book of Genesis, often serve multiple purposes:
Genealogies:
Here are the three categories of Biblical genealogies:

Familial (or domestic) genealogies: Concerned with inheritance and privileges of firstborn sons.
Legal-political genealogies: Centered on claims to a hereditary office. Establishing ancestry for land organization, territorial groupings, and military service.
Religious genealogies: Used to establish membership in the Aaronic and Levitical priesthoods.

I quote Reason's to Believe:

Biblical genealogies fall into three main categories according to
their purpose:  familial, legal-political, and religious.4 Familial
(or domestic) genealogies were primarily concerned about inheritance
and privileges of firstborn sons.  Legal-political genealogies are
primarily centered on claims to a hereditary office, but other
examples include establishing ancestry for land organization,
territorial groupings, and military service.  Religious genealogies
were primarily used to establish membership in the Aaronic and
Levitical priesthoods.  The function of a genealogy largely determines
its structure and organization.  In each of these cases, there is
little reason or need to give a complete listing of names since it is
ancestry, not the actual number of generations that is important.


So, as you said, the order of names may not always be about chronological birth order. It could be the significance of the characters or their role in the narrative. Let me then present some possibilities.
1. It is possible that the oldest was born during the flood, the second born shortly after the flood and Arphaxad being born two years after the flood. This would leave a window of time for this to be possible.
I find this option less likely for the following reason:
For starters the Bible does not record anyone born during the flood. (I think there's more than arguments from silence though).
Furthermore, Genesis 9:18-19 states:

18 Now the sons of Noah who went out of the ark were Shem, Ham, and
Japheth. And Ham was the father of Canaan. 19 These three were the
sons of Noah, and from these the whole earth was populated.

2. Born after the flood.
I will not say absolutely that it does, but this passage might imply that all of Noah’s grandchildren, including Elam and Asshur, were born after the flood, as they are included in "the whole earth was populated" and that is stated directly after saying that the sons of Noah "went out of the ark".
This does not mean that it's not possible that they were all born within that time period!
There's nothing that necessitates the list not being in chronological order.
The genealogical account in Genesis 11:10 simply states, “Shem was a hundred years old, and begat Arphaxad two years after the flood.” This does not specify the exact timing within that second year. If Arphaxad was indeed born towards the end of the second year, it could theoretically allow a short window of time for the births of Elam and Asshur before him, assuming that the listing in Genesis 10:22 is chronological, which is not necessarily the case.

In reality though the genealogy’s order might not be strictly by age but could be about the prominence of the individuals and their nations in biblical history.
3. What we haven't considered is political importance as a possibility for the listing.
The genealogies spend a lot of time focused of the nations that were birthed out of them.
Elam: (identified with a region and people in what is now southwestern Iran.)

Genesis 14:1: And it came to pass in the days of Amraphel king of
Shinar, Arioch king of Ellasar, Chedorlaomer king of Elam, and Tidal
king of nations,

Elam here is mentioned as part of a coalition of kings, with Chedorlaomer as the king of Elam. They waged war against the kings of the Dead Sea region.
This lends credence to Elam’s involvement in regional politics and conflicts.

Isaiah 11:11: The prophet Isaiah lists Elam among the places
from which God will gather His people who were scattered.
Isaiah 21:2: Elam is mentioned in a prophecy against Babylon,
where the Elamites are called to battle. They must have had military
capability.
Jeremiah 49:34-39: A prophecy against Elam is given, which
speaks of its future judgment, so it had some prominence in the
ancient world.

Asshur: (associated with the Assyrian Empire)
Encyclopedia of The Bible – Asshur

ASSHUR ăsh’ ər (אַשּׁ֑וּר, meaning uncertain). Name of the son of
Shem, borne also by the patron deity, people, and capital city of
Assyria. (See Assyria.)
The son of Shem (Gen 10:22; 1 Chron 1:17) was considered to be the
founder of the Assyrian nation, whose king list names the earliest
founders as tent-dwellers in the southern and western deserts (cf. Gen
10:11 KJV). The Assyrians were similarly named (Ezra 4:2; Ezek 27:23;
32:22; Hos 14:3 KJV), though sometimes the reference could equally
well be to the national god Ashur of the same name (Num 24:22-24; Ps
83:8 KJV). This god’s name occurs as an element in many personal names
(e.g. Ashurbanipal, Esarhaddon) and may well account for the name
given to the capital city.

Genesis 10:11: Nineveh, the great city (feared by Jonah), is associated with the Assyrian Empire.

Ashur – Important Religious Center: The city was Assyria's oldest
capital, which was already known during Akkadian and Sumerian times.
It was also an important religious center for worship of the supreme
god Ashur, who became the national god of Assyria and protected the
Assyrian kings. He was venerated along with Enlil and Ninurta, god of
agriculture, scribes, hunting, and war. Several Assyrian kings had the
god Ashur's protection in their names.

Isaiah 10:5-12: Assyria is referred to as the rod of God’s anger that is used to punish Israel. it was a dominant power used by God for His purposes.
Jonah 1:1-2: God sends Jonah to Nineveh, the "great city" of Assyria, to call it to repentance. This was a rather important city in the Bible.
Arphaxad:
Genesis 11:10-26: The genealogy from Shem to Abram (Abraham) includes Arphaxad. This is line through which the covenant with Abraham and the nation of Israel would come.
Luke 3:36: In the genealogy of Jesus, Arphaxad is listed, linking him to the messianic lineage.
All this is to says that Arphaxad was not as politically dominant as Elam or Assyria was.
We see that in the Bible Elam and Asshur are depicted as powerful entities in their time, with Elam being one of the oldest civilizations and Asshur representing the Assyrian Empire.
Arphaxad on the other hand was not the founder of a great empire like Elam or Assyria. God often uses the lowly in his great plan. Arphaxad played his own role as the ancestor of the Hebrews and the line through which God’s redemptive plan unfolds, culminating in the coming of the Messiah.
The Hebrews political structure was initially tribal and decentralized. It wasn’t really until the time of Saul, David, and Solomon that the Israelites established a unified monarchy that could be considered a significant political entity in the region. Even then, the kingdom of Israel and later the divided kingdoms of Israel and Judah were smaller and less powerful than their imperial neighbors.

Hm, this is interesting. Are there any other cases in biblical genealogies where something similar occurred, with sons being cited for political importance?

It might be argued. The whole messianic line, starting from the genealogy of Judah, is significant due to its connection to the royal lineage. This in itself can be cited for political importance as it was the kingly line. In the account of Judah’s twin sons, Perez and Zerah, Perez is given prominence in the genealogy leading to King David. I will consider if there are more possibilities for your question.
